# Mirrored object is textured incorrectly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, materials, mirror

While making the eyes for a character I was creating, I came across an issue where when I mirrored the first eyeball, the result was textured incorrectly.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the original eyeball (on the right) has sort of a gradient on the iris where the *outer rim is a darker brown than the inner rim*. But then, if you look at the mirrored eyeball (on the left), it completely loses the effect and just becomes what looks like a solid color. I have tried applying the mirror modifier but it does nothing.

This effect was 100% procedural and achieved through a node setup I found in a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0Rqwm8sUkw). I'll also share it here for convenience. If anyone is wondering, the ColorRamp actually has two colors except they are extremely close to each other. I can share the file as well if anyone needs it. The white and the pupil of the eyeball are separate materials.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

i think this is a better approach, since setting the texture coordinate node to object will take that object's origin as the center point for the gradient to start, i also used a linear gradient and rotated it with a mapping node since its easier to handle, setting it to generated will set the center of the gradient to the mesh and not the object's origin